# PHP как превратить маску в диапазон IP адресов?

Tags: php, сеть, ip

Есть коллекция записей вида:

> 1.0.0.0/24
>
> 1.0.1.0/24
>
> 1.0.2.0/23
>
> 1.0.4.0/22
>
> 1.0.8.0/21

Как мне их превратить в диапазон адресов на php?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.network.php#17580

> Преобразует CIDR, например:
> 0.0.0.0/16 -> 0.0.0.0 - 0.0.255.255
> 127.0/16 -> 127.0.0.0 - 127.0.255.255
> и т.д...

```
function cidrconv($net) { 
$start=strtok($net,"/"); 
$n=3-substr_count($net, "."); 
if ($n>0) { for ($i=$n;$i>0;$i--) $start.=".0"; } 
$bits1=str_pad(decbin(ip2long($start)),32,"0","STR_PAD_LEFT"); 
$net=pow(2,(32-substr(strstr($net,"/"),1)))-1; 
$bits2=str_pad(decbin($net),32,"0","STR_PAD_LEFT"); 
for ($i=0;$i<32;$i++) { 
if ($bits1[$i]==$bits2[$i]) $final.=$bits1[$i]; 
if ($bits1[$i]==1 and $bits2[$i]==0) $final.=$bits1[$i]; 
if ($bits1[$i]==0 and $bits2[$i]==1) $final.=$bits2[$i]; 
} 
return $start." - ".long2ip(bindec($final)); 
}
```